# friendlyid for custom url not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm having a Offer model and having custom url like:

```
get "all-offers/:id"=> "offers#aff_offers"
```

How to use friendly id for this custom url.
Note- Already done required migration in offer model and added this two line in offer model

```
 extend FriendlyId
 friendly_id :offer_name, use: :slugged
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe FriendlyID adds a field called `slug` to your model. So, it is quite easy to work with this. In your `offers` controller under your `aff_offers` action just do the following:

```
def aff_offers
  offer = Offer.find_by(slug: params[:id])
end
```

This will let something like `/all-offers/boats-half-off` look up an offer with slug having the value of "boats-half-off"